# Как расположить блок №3 справа, а блоки №1 и №2 слева друг под другом?

Tags: css

```css
.page-50-percentage {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(50% - 22px);
}
```

```html
<div id="html-frame">
  <div id="1" class="page-50-percentage">id="1"
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="page-50-percentage">id="2"
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="page-50-percentage">id="3"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант на гридах: **

```css
#html-frame {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-areas: "first third" "second third";
}

#first,
#second,
#third {
  background: pink;
}

#first {
  grid-area: first;
}

#second {
  grid-area: second
}

#third {
  grid-area: third;
}
```

```html
<div id="html-frame">
  <div id="first" class="page-50-percentage">id="first"
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="page-50-percentage">id="second"
  </div>
  <div id="third" class="page-50-percentage">id="third"
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант на флексах: **

```css
#html-frame {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#first,
#second,
#third {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: pink;
}

#third {
  align-self: center;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="html-frame">
  <div class='left'>
    <div id="first" class="page-50-percentage">id="first"
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="page-50-percentage">id="second"
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="third" class="page-50-percentage">id="third"
  </div>
</div>
```

**Флоаты: **

```css
#html-frame::after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

#first,
#second,
#third {
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px;
  background: pink;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
}

.cleafix {
  clear: both;
}

#third {
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="html-frame">
  <div class='left'>
    <div id="first" class="page-50-percentage">id="first"
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="page-50-percentage">id="second"
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="third" class="page-50-percentage">id="third"
  </div>
  <div class='clearfix'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: он не разберётся с grid :))

Comment: @MaximLensky, добавил флексы. Может их знает...

Comment: сразу видно разницу ..на гриде лучше